# HTML5 semantic markup ignored in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, semantic-markup

I'm trying to use semantic tags on my page (http://toytic.com/class/html5_docStructure.html ). I expected them to behave like normal markup tags without any styling information (e.g. display block.

However when I look DOM structure in the IE7 debugger, I see that the tags are imidatly closed and all style attributes are ignored.

[image: HTML tag markup in IE7]

I know their are libraries like modinizer, but what I have read so far, they just use the CSS trick, where they set the following CSS attribute, so the browser interprets the semantic elements like normal divs:

```
header, nav, article, footer, section, aside, figure, figcaption {
            display: block;
        }
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old versions of IE that do not understand the new tags in HTML5 require a little JavaScript trick, called a 'shiv', to enable them for display and styling. Setting the CSS to `display: block` alone will not do the trick.

The HTML5Shiv can be included by itself, or packaged with a wider library such as Modernizr (which you really should be using in any case).

HTMLShiv: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Not 'older browsers', just  'old IE'.

Comment: modernizr does the trick and I dont't need to get any deeper into that topic. Thanks I'm using the online version from //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) plugin to give the older browsers fallbacks for HTML5. Just embed it in your head tag script after downloading the minified version. You can also use [HTML5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

I also recommend when you do websites, boot it up with [initialzr](http://www.initializr.com/). It'll give you all the dependencies you need.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr also uses something comparable to [HTML5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js) which adds the elements [to the DOM](http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie) as well. Check out what happens in that JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Make sure that "html5shiv v3.6" is checked when you download Modernizr.